# Maven/Eclipse external jar troubleshooting

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, jar

My question is: how do I add external jar-libraries to a jsp/maven/eclipse project?
Second question; if my problem is, as i suspect, a wrong syntax in my pom.xml-file; what is the right one?

I am a mediocerly experienced java developer, and I am seeking to expand my expertise to Servlets and jsp-programming. I am in the process of experimenting with this.

I have gotten help to set up a maven3/eclipse (kepler) work station, and I have successfully gone through a couple of basic tutorials. However, I am experiencing severe difficulties getting external .jar's to work with my code. I have tried several solutions.

1. One bullet-proof solution offered online was simply putting my jars in WEB-INF/lib, and importing them through <%@ page import=...
   the import works with packages already included, i.e. Math etc. It does not work with external jars, in the lib-folder. Build path is configured like a normal eclipse java project.
2. After suspecting that I failed to specify that I was using maven, when searching for a solution, and that it was indeed an important detail, I found a lot of different suggestions in regards to the pom.xml-file. Dependencies and repositories were the buzz-words. I tried a few different copy-paste solutions, but now my project won't even build anymore. Here is my error message when i try to start up the jetty server, and build the project:

   ```
   H:\projects\xxx-releaseplan>mvn jetty:run
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO]
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building xxx-releaseplan Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO]
   [INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.13.v20130916:run (default-cli) @ xxx-releaseplan >>>
   [WARNING] The POM for com.xxx.mrpb.model.jar:com.xxx.mrpb.model.jar:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information availabl
   e
   [WARNING] The POM for com.xxx.mrpb.viewmodel.jar:com.xxx.mrpb.viewmodel.jar:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information
   available
   [WARNING] The POM for servlet-api-2.5.jar:servlet-api-2.5.jar:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 0.299s
   [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 25 13:47:26 CET 2014
   [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/61M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx-releaseplan: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.releaseplan
   :xxx-releaseplan:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.xxx.mrpb.model.jar:com.xxx.mrpb.mode
   l.jar:jar:1.0, com.xxx.mrpb.viewmodel.jar:com.xxx.mrpb.viewmodel.jar:jar:1.0, servlet-api-2.5.jar:servlet-api-2.5.jar:jar:
   2.5: Failure to find com.xxx.mrpb.model.jar:com.xxx.mrpb.model.jar:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cach
   ed in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updat
   es are forced -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
   H:\projects\xxx-releaseplan>
   ```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dk.sdc.releaseplan</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdc-releaseplan</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sdc-releaseplan Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dk.sdc.mrpb.model.jar</groupId>
            <artifactId>dk.sdc.mrpb.model.jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dk.sdc.mrpb.viewmodel.jar</groupId>
            <artifactId>dk.sdc.mrpb.viewmodel.jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>servlet-api-2.5.jar</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5.jar</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>sdc-releaseplan</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!--<plugin> <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId> <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>jshint</goal> 
                </goals> </execution> </executions> <configuration> <options>devel,evil,noarg</options> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>********************************************</echo>
                                <echo>***** This project REQUIRES Maven 3.0+ *****</echo>
                                <echo>********************************************</echo>
                                <echo>mvn jetty:run - Running as un-assembled webapp</echo>
                                <echo>mvn jetty:run-war - Running as assembled webapp</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Jetty Version: 8.x Home: Eclipse, Codehaus Java Version: 1.6 Protocols: 
                    HTTP/1.1 RFC2616, WebSocket, SPDY Servlet Version: 3.0 JSP Version: 2.1 http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty -->
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.13.v20130916</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved
```

says that the jar files are not available in the repository location : http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

This is configured in the settings.xml of the M2_HOME. Check that the version of the jar file is available in the repo or not.

If you can recheck that the dependencies are available, then check your internet connection to download that.

If the jar files are downloaded, then check `users/.m2/repository/<your artifact path>` to check it is downloaded properly.

Comment: In other words, my downloaded jar-files should be placed within the repository folder? Let me try that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to have generated a whole mess of useless folders within the repository...

Comment: If you can take the risk of downloading all the jar files again, then you can delete the repository and run mvn clean install. It will download you all the jar files

Comment: I do not think that will work. The .jar-files i am trying to use, are some I have generated myself. They contain the model classes of a stand-alone application, which i am trying to make into a web application.

Comment: So I said its risk. Then you need to adjust either the profile you are  using and make sure that all the jars present in the .m2/repository

Comment: I am pretty sure you are on to something there. I've had unneccessary long names on my jar-files, but now they are actually working. I have a new issue, but imports are actually working. thank you very much. I am impressed you were able to help, considering I was not very good at asking a precise question! :)